# Continuously reading from serial port asynchronously properly

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, serial-port

I'm just going to preface this by saying I just started trying to use Async today, so I have a very limited understanding of what I am doing.

I was previously using threads to read data from a serial port, process that data into data to write, and then writing it. I had 1 thread reading data and placing it into a buffer, another thread processing data from a buffer, and a final thread writing it. This way if I clicked a button, I could send additional data.

Now I am just trying to learn and ensure I am doing everything properly, so I am trying to read data from the serial port, and add that data to a multilined textbox. Here's the code:

Connect to serial port, if successful, call `UpdateMessageBox` which is async:

```
private void serialConnectClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_serialConnected)
    {
        _serialConnected = SerialConnect(portCombo.Text, int.Parse(baudCombo.Text));
        if (!_serialConnected)
        {
            portCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
            messageTextBox.Text += "Failed to connect.\r\n";
            return;
        }

        serialConnectBtn.Text = "Disconnect";
        serialStatusLabel.Text = "Serial: Connected";
        serialStatusLabel.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        messageTextBox.Text += "Connected\r\n";
        VDIportCombo.Enabled = false;
        soundSuccess.Play();
        UpdateMessageBox(); // this is an async function
    }
}
```

This continuously calls `ReadLineAsync` and adds the result to the textbox:

```
public async Task UpdateMessageBox()
{
    messageTextBox.Text += "Reading data from serial.";
    while (_serialConnected)
    {
        string message = await SerialReadLineAsync(serial);
        messageTextBox.Text += message;
    }
}
```

And this does `ReadAsync` on the `SerialPort.BaseStream`, and only returns data when we get a full line (denoted by a newline character):

```
async Task<string> SerialReadLineAsync(SerialPort serialPort)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
    string result = string.Empty;
    Debug.WriteLine("Let's start reading.");

    while (true)
    {
        await serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);
        result += serialPort.Encoding.GetString(buffer);

        if (result.EndsWith(serialPort.NewLine))
        {
            result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - serialPort.NewLine.Length);
            result.TrimEnd('\r','\n');
            Debug.Write(string.Format("Data: {0}", result));
            result += "\r\n";
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing everything correctly? Can I call an async method from the UI thread? Visual studios is telling me I *should* use await, but it is just suggesting that.

I want other code to run on the UI thread while it is continuously reading, so I don't want to `await` the `UpdateMessageBox` function. If this were a thread, I would just want the read thread to operate in the background, and I would just do `myReadThread.Start()`, is there something similar for async?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, this code does work, but I want to know if it's the "proper" way to do what I am doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change:

```
private void serialConnectClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

to

```
private async void serialConnectClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

...and change the call to `UpdateMessageBox();` to:

```
await UpdateMessageBox().ConfigureAwait(true);
```

`UpdateMessageBox` should use `ConfigureAwait(true)` in order to capture the current context (UI) else the `messageTextBox.Text += message;` would execute on a different thread:

```
public async Task UpdateMessageBox()
{
    messageTextBox.Text += "Reading data from serial.";
    while (_serialConnected)
    {
        string message = await SerialReadLineAsync(serial).ConfigureAwait(true);
        messageTextBox.Text += message;
    }
}
```

In `SerialReadLineAsync`, you can change:

```
await serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);
```

...to:

```
await serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

...because `SerialReadLineAsync` statements are not related to the UI.

The general tip is *"async all the way"* which means any method that `await`s an `async` method also needs to be made `async` and in turn `await`ed.  Repeat this up the call-stack.

Comment: Ah, didn't know I could make that function async! Is there a way I don't have to `await` the `UpdateMessageBox`? When I include the `await` keyword, I get `IOexceptions` when I press the button a second time (which currently is programmed to close the serial port)

Comment: For anyone in the future, you can! Just add `.ConfigureAwait(false);` so, it should be `UpdateMessageBox().ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: You sure can. Just be careful about using `ConfigureAwait(false)` during a UI method else the statement immediately following could potentially executed on a different thread.  Otherwise, if you don't care about what thread to use, use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. [Tell me more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)