# C# visual studio reading a data pack every ms with the serial port

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port

I have a window form application that needs to read in a byte array once every ms. The byte array varies in size, but will never be longer than 36 bytes. The code I currently have seems to omit some of the data packages. One of the bytes in the package is a count, so I can tell some of the packages are being missed. After serialPort1.Read(data, 0, bytesToRead) the rest of the code is just to process the byte array into an int array and add it to a list. That code all works like I expect it to.

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

       int bytesToRead = serialPort1.BytesToRead; 
       byte[] data = new byte[bytesToRead];
       serialPort1.Read(data, 0, bytesToRead); 

       data = replaceBytes(data);
       long[] dataIntigerValuesPlusCountValue = convertDataToInt(data);
       List<long> dataIntigerValuePlusCountValueList = dataIntigerValuePlusCountValue.OfType<long>().ToList();
       dataList.Add(dataIntigerValuePlusCountValueList);

}
```

Comment: my guess is that your code takes around 1ms or more to run then.. expecting MS accuracy is a hard thing

Comment: What might be a way to speed it up? Each of those methods I apply to it are pretty short

Comment: Use two threads and a queue. One thread does nothing except read data from the port and put it in the queue. The other thread, pulls data from the queue and processes it. That way your thread that reads the incoming data does as little as possible (reducing overhead), and the queue acts as a buffer to allow processing time.

Comment: What would that code look like? I am relatively new to c# and have not used threading before. would I add the threads into the serialPort1_DataRecieved event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a window form application that needs to read in a byte array once every ms.

First off, you shouldn't have to read 'every ms', you'll lock up the UI if you're in the UI thread (which you are since you're not using threading).

> The byte array varies in size, but will never be longer than 36 bytes.

Instead of trying to read a single packet every MS, you should buffer data, 36 bytes at a time, and then process it. E.g. Ready 36 bytes, find the byte which tells you how long the packet should be, then process that many bytes. On your next serial port read, concatenate the array of any unused bytes with the next 36 bytes you read (your buffer array size should be at least 72 bytes, and on each loop, you should check if the current size is greater than 36, and if it is, loop an additional time so that at a given time, you have at most 1 full packet in the byte array buffer).

Also, instead of blocking the UI thread, and instead of utilizing threads, you should use async/await continuously read read data and then process your data that way. [How to continually read data asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732358/continuously-reading-from-serial-port-asynchronously-properly).

That way you would get the packet size, then wait for the buffer to be the appropriate size, then you process the data.

The way you're currently doing it will drop the extra data buffered and desync your connection. That said, you should also try and use a flag byte (or a newline character) to signify the start or end of packet. Obviously if it's not your hardware you can't control that, but if you can, that would guarantee the stream never desyncs.

TL:DR: Timing is unreliable, just process the packets as they are received.

Comment: Thanks that sounds like it might help. Would you be able to give a sample of what that code will look like I don't really know how to proceed? Also there's no byte that tells me how long each packet should be, but each packet starts with 0xC0 and 0x02, and ends with 0xC0

Comment: Also the reason I have to read every ms is that the program is collecting data that has a sample rate of 1 ms.

Comment: @user9964422 oh perfect, knowing the start and end bytes will work best! I'll edit my answer with some quick pseudo code on what to do. Also, just because the device has a poll rate of 1ms doesn't mean you have to process the data one at time at the 1ms interval, but I think it'll make more sense when I show you an example. Gimme a bit to edit my answer

Comment: thank you! will I write this code in the serialPort1_DataReceived event still? Seeing the pseudo code will definitely help