# Cannot fill text box after scanning barcode

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I developing a barcode scanning program. The issue I face is i cannot fill a `TextBox` after scanning the barcode. Below is my code.

```
Private Sub serialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    If TextBox1.Text.Length >= 20 Then
        serialPort.Close()
    Else
        DispString = serialPort.ReadExisting()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Focus()
    serialPort.PortName = "COM1"
    serialPort.BaudRate = "9600"
    serialPort.Parity = Parity.None
    serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One
    serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None
    serialPort.Open()
    serialPort.ReadTimeout = 200

    If serialPort.IsOpen Then
        DispString = ""
        txtCardKeyDeactivate.Text = ""
    End If

Private Sub SendSerialData(ByVal data As String)
    ' Send strings to a serial port.
    Using COM13 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM1")
        COM13.WriteLine(data)
    End Using
End Sub
Private Sub ReceiveSerialData(ByVal data As String)

    Dim returnStr As String = ""
    Dim COM13 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing
    Try
        COM13 = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM1")
        COM13.ReadTimeout = 10000
        Do
            Dim Incoming As String = COM13.ReadLine()
            If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                returnStr &= Incoming & vbCrLf
            End If
        Loop
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        returnStr = "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
    Finally
        If COM13 IsNot Nothing Then COM13.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see anything like `TextBox1 = ???`

Comment: Nor anything about the `ms-access` tag.

Comment: T.S my testbox 1 is a part of tools on my program. sorry i am noyt get what you mean

Comment: JQSOFT i no post my access database command, i just post the barcode scan source code

Comment: No, according to your code your textbox is `TextBox1`, and there is no place at all in your code that tries to write the barcode to it after getting it from the serial port.

Comment: @JQSOFT mean i need write the do loop my my textbox 1 right

Comment: You need to append what you receive from the serial port into the text box. Doing that in the `Do..Loop` block is a bad idea because your UI is gonna freeze. You should do that in the DataReceived event of the SerialPort.

Comment: Your DataReceived event is not properly setup, it is missing the handles clause: `Private Sub serialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles serialPort.DataReceived`

Comment: @JQSOFT i need add the do loop on my serial port data receive program am i right

Comment: I think that you are trying to use the code from [How to: Receive Strings From Serial Ports in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/computer-resources/how-to-receive-strings-from-serial-ports) which doesn't cover the TextBox part. Please take some tips and tricks from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732358/continuously-reading-from-serial-port-asynchronously-properly). Good luck.